# Unable to Open/Install Git on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, version-control, administrator

When I open the file I downloaded from https://git-scm.com/download and then Windows, nothing happens. I've tried running it as a normal user and administrator but nothing happens. Not even a processor in the Task Manager opens.

What could cause this? Is it because Git hasn't been updated for Windows 10 yet, or is it something else? I just did a clean install of Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you could try chocolatey (even if I'm not sure it will change something...) :

https://chocolatey.org/packages/git

Or the RC for the next to be released git for Windows :

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: I didn't know about Releases. I've always just used the ones at the download page, but now I see that was simply Previews or something? The second link you provided worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's release candidates of the next version to be released, the 2.4 (or 2.5) after a very long stagnation at the version 1.95. They did a really great job to fill the gap...

Comment: I had a problem installing the original exe file since the installation wizard was disappearing after a few seconds and I am guessing it was the security tool installed on the company laptop, this one installed it, you have to run it as ADMINISTRATOR though

Answer (score 0):

**Try running the installer from command prompt.**

#### More details

This is what just happened to me. When double-clicked, or even ran as admin, `Git-2.34.1-64-bit.exe` shows this. None of those 3 buttons work.

[image: Nothing works when double clicking]

The only thing that helped was running the file from command prompt.

[image: Everything works when ran from cmd.exe]

This is a weird one.

#### Update

A similar thing just happened again with `node-v17.3.0-x64`. This time, I would get this screen even when running from command prompt.

[image: Node.JS fails to install from cmd.exe...]

But it would work just fine if the cmd.exe is ran as an administrator.

[image: ...but it works if cmd.exe is ran as administrator.]

It's maddening.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this.

All I had to do was put the ".exe" at the end of the file name and double click.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem
I changed the downloaded file's name to 'git.exe' then I was succeeded to install it.